# rewrite query without DENSE_RANK

Tags: oracle

I have one very slow query and try to optimize response time by using a materialized view. But one part is not compatible with General Restrictions on Fast Refresh.
How to rewrite it without DENSE_RANK?

```
create table t (id,object_id,log_cre_date) as        
select 1,2,to_date('18/5/2010, 08:00','dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mi') from dual union all
select 2,2,to_date('18/5/2010, 10:00','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 3,3,to_date('18/5/2010, 11:00','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 4,3,to_date('18/5/2010, 12:10','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 5,4,to_date('18/5/2010, 12:20','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 6,4,to_date('18/5/2010, 11:30','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual;

SELECT
    MAX(t.id) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY log_cre_date ASC) id,
    t.object_id
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    t.object_id
```

Comment: Analytic functions usually give optimal performance.  Why would you want to rewrite this?

Comment: To be free from restriction on creating materialized view with fast refresh on commit and possible use pre saved data.

Comment: Do you want solution without any analytical function or without only dense_rank?

Comment: First is to try any solution that allows me to create a materialised view.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the accepted answer is fast refreshable.  Here is a query that definitely is:

```
SELECT max(cast(to_char(t.log_cre_date,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || lpad(t.id,30,'0') as varchar2(80))) maxid,
       t.object_id,
       COUNT(*) cnt
FROM   t
GROUP BY t.object_id;
```

The idea is to append the `id` to the `log_cre_date` and take the max of the concatenation.  That way, you can extract the `id` you need later.

So, to get the `id`, you would do this:

```
SELECT to_char(substr(maxid,-30)) id, object_id 
FROM your_materialized_view;
```

You could put that in a view to hide the complexity.

Here is a full example:

#### Create the base table

```
DROP TABLE t;

create table t (id,object_id,log_cre_date) as        
select 1,2,to_date('18/5/2010, 08:00','dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mi') from dual union all
select 2,2,to_date('18/5/2010, 10:00','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 3,3,to_date('18/5/2010, 11:00','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 4,3,to_date('18/5/2010, 12:10','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 5,4,to_date('18/5/2010, 12:20','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual union all
select 6,4,to_date('18/5/2010, 11:30','dd/mm/yyyy, hh mi') from dual;
```

#### Add some constraints to allow fast-refresh MV

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY id NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id );
```

#### Create a snapshot log to enable fast refresh

```
--DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON t;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON t WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY (OBJECT_ID, LOG_CRE_DATE) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

#### Create the materialized view (note presence of `COUNT(*)` in select-list.  Important!

```
--DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW t_mv;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW t_mv
  REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS
SELECT max(cast(to_char(t.log_cre_date,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || lpad(t.id,30,'0') as varchar2(80))) maxid,
       t.object_id,
       COUNT(*) cnt
FROM   t
GROUP BY t.object_id;
```

#### Test it out

```
select to_number(substr(maxid,-30)) id, object_id
from t_mv;
```

> ```
> +----+-----------+
> | ID | OBJECT_ID |
> +----+-----------+
> |  2 |         2 |
> |  4 |         3 |
> |  5 |         4 |
> +----+-----------+
> ```

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE id = 5;

COMMIT;

select to_number(substr(maxid,-30)) id, object_id
from t_mv;
```

> ```
> +----+-----------+
> | ID | OBJECT_ID |
> +----+-----------+
> |  4 |         3 |
> |  5 |         4 |
> |  1 |         2 |    -- Now ID #1 is the latest for object_id 2
> +----+-----------+
> ```

Comment: 1. Could you explain why the COUNT(*) should be used?
2. MIN no MAX
3. Can i use this SELECT to_number(substr(min(cast(to_char(t.log_cre_date,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || lpad(t.id,20,'0') as varchar2(80))),-20)) minid, in materialized view?

Comment: 1) Not _should_, _must_ -- if you want fast refresh on a materialized view with aggregates.  It's in the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024).  Read up on `DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW` -- if your MV is not fast-refreshable for some reason, that will tell you why.  2) I'll assume you can replace `MIN` for `MAX`.  3.  No, it would be nice, but you cannot.  Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the restriction but I am not sure if following query will work or not.

Try this and let us know if it works.

```
Select t.id, t.object_id from
T join
(SELECT
    min(log_cre_date) mindt,
    t.object_id
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    t.object_id) t1
On t.object_id = t1.object_id
And t.log_cre_date = t1.mindt;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: It seems that this is the only option so far.
I did not want to write at the very beginning that my version was similar. I just wanted to avoid join on a date.
`WITH
    src as (
select object_id, min(log_cre_date) log_cre_date
from t
GROUP by object_id
    )
select t.id, t.object_id from src
inner join t on t.object_id = src.object_id and t.log_cre_date=src.log_cre_date
ORDER by t.object_id;`

Comment: Be careful if there is a possibility that two `id` values for the same `object_id` can have the exact same `log_cre_date`.  This query would give multiple rows for a single `object_id` in that situation, something the original query would not do.

Comment: Also, the OP's query actually returns the `id` having the _minimum_ `log_cre_date` for each `object_id`, since he used `DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ... ASC`.  I am guessing you interpreted his intention correctly though and that that was just a bug on the OP's part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query will run faster:

```
select object_id, id
from (
    select object_id, first_value(id) over(partition by object_id order by log_cre_date) as id
    from t
)
group by object_id, id;
```

Hope it helps!